# Do dead letter queues create new threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I have following RabbitMQ listener:

```
class TestClass {
  private ThreadLocal<Integer> myThreadLocal =
    new ThreadLocal<Integer>() {
        @Override public Integer initialValue() {
            return 0;
        }
  };

  @RabbitListener("${test.queue}")
  public void listener(Message message) {
    // some logic

    incrementThreadLocalValueByOne();

    // some logic

    if(/*some condition*/) {
      deadletterMessagetoTestQueue();
    } else {
      doSomethingElse();
    }
  }
}
```

Program is roughly written. Methods do what their names suggest.

My question is this:

1. When *deadletterMessagetoTestQueue()* method is called will it create a new thread when sending the message again to *test.queue*?
2. If it does, that means thread will be re-initialized with 0. What is the thread was static?

Let me know if questions needs more clarity. Thanks :)

Comment: `>When deadletterMessagetoTestQueue() method is called will it create a new thread when sending the message again to test.queue?` You need to show it's code for anyone to answer that; if it simply does a send, then no.

Comment: Thanks. It only sends.